# VS2012 reference manager clearing recent references

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Does anyone know how to clear the list of references in the recent sub-category of the Browse option?

At work we work from many branches and it is annoying to have this list as hardly ever do I need to add the same reference to a project which I had previously added to another project.

Just wondered if there was a way to clean up or turn off this "functionality"

Thanks.

[image: Reference Manager]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right click one of the recent references and you should get a popup dialog that allows you to either remove the reference (the one you clicked on) or clear all recent references.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2015 right clicking does not work. However, if you select the entry and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key that does work.